# javascript: unshift an object to an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that i need to insert in the front(first index) of an array of object.

```
const static_stat = {id: null, name: 'UNASSIGNED'};
api_data = [{id:.., name:..},{id:.., name:..},{id:.., name:..}];
```

I've tried using `unshift`, What I want is to achieve the result below, but it gives me the length of the array instead.

```
[{id:null, name: 'UNASSIGNED'},{id:.., name:..},{id:.., name:..},{id:.., name:..}]
```

Comment: unshift like push returns the length of the array after the item is added

Comment: @JaromandaX So how do I make it to return an object tho?

Comment: unshift adds whatever to the array and returns new length ... you can't change that

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) mutates the array and returns the new length of the array.

---

For getting a new array, you could use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
return [static_stat].concat(api_data);
```

or take a new array with spreaded items.

```
return [static_stat, ...api_data];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. The [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array. But after using `unshift()` your original array `api_data` has been already updated. Just use a `console.log(api_data)` on it to see the updated array with new `static_stat` object like:

```js
const static_stat = {id: null, name: 'UNASSIGNED'};
let api_data = [{id: 1, name: 'Jhon'}];

console.log(api_data.unshift(static_stat));

console.log(api_data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```